# Flex Components are not getting refreshed

Tags: flex4, flash, refresh

Hi We are using Flex 4 in our project on UI side. On loading the application dashboard, we get a set of pods. We click on a pod and the pod view opens. This pod view contains datagrid with the first column as a hyperlink. When you click on hyperlink another screen opens which is our module screen.

This module screen has a SUBMIT button on top and a couple of datagrids. Now we load data in the grids using RemoteObject. The parent container for each of the grid is a WindowShade Component.

Now our requirement is that the user can make modifications in one or both of the grids and click SUBMIT. Depending upon which grid the user has modified I want to make the corresponding Window shade as read only. IF the user modifies both the grids, I need to make both the Window Shade components as read only and disable the SUBMIT button. **The user should be able to see this change immediately on click of SUBMIT without closing the screen or navigating away from the screen.**

When the user opens screen for the first time, we get some statuses from backend and Depending upon these statuses, I make the Window shades as read only and enable/disable the buttons. When I click SUBMIT, I still hit the backend and get the status but no enabling/disabling of buttons or window shade happens.

I have written the logic for enabling/disabling in the updateComplete method of my mxml file for which swf is created.

the updateComplete gets called when user opens screen for the first time.It does not get called when the user clicks SUBMIT. why is it so?

I have tried using Loader and SWFLoader to load my SWF file as below but it is not working either. 
var request:URLRequest = new URLRequest("com/citi/risk/credit/maintenance/view/widgets/CRCMaintenanceModule.swf");
var loader:Loader = new Loader();
loader.load(request);

Any help or pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Two things you may want to consider:

1) In short, `FlexEvent.UPDATE_COMPLETE` is an event that gets dispatched has completed rendering itself (gone through a Flex component life cycle). This could happen once, or many times depending on how often the component changes and it's state needs to be re-rendered.

The frequency/timing of this event will vary based on the object that is dispatching it. For example a container that is being resized will dispatch this numerous time. A label that never changes may only do it once.

Instead, you should consider adding a "creationComplete" (`FlexEvent.CREATION_COMPLETE`) event listener. "creationComplete" only happens once, you can add the listener to any object that contains the submit button.

2) When you click submit, the object you've added the "updateComplete" listener to probably hasn't changed enough to go through Flex's component life cycle. So no event is dispatched.

The answer to why this doesn't happen actually depends on which object you have added the event listener to.

Have you tried using a "click" handler on the submit button, so you could disable the appropriate elements when the button is clicked?  Again, the "click" event will happen only once, unlike "updateComplete" ;)

Comment: Hi Sunil, I ran the app in debug mode and what you have said is correct. I also found that the update complete of the main container gets called before I get data from the remote object. So all the status checks I have put in the update complete method of the main container go in vain. How do I ensure that I get data from the server before the update complete gets called? If I am able to get the data before update complete, my problem is solved.

Comment: Don't use update complete for that. Perhaps your view should have a default state (things disabled) until the response from the server call is received. Then enable things, and disable again w/the submit button click handler.

Comment: Again, to reiterate: update complete means one (out of possibly many) rendering phase of the object has completed. So it is not appropriate for what you are doing.